# How to solve ArrayList outOfBoundsExeption?

Tags: android, collision-detection, html-canvas

I'm getting:

```
    09-02 17:15:39.140: E/AndroidRuntime(533): java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Invalid index 1, size is 1
    09-02 17:15:39.140: E/AndroidRuntime(533):  at java.util.ArrayList.throwIndexOutOfBoundsException(ArrayList.java:251)
```

when I'm killing enemies using this method:

```
    private void checkCollision() {
    Rect h1 = happy.getBounds();
    for (int i = 0; i < enemies.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < bullets.size(); j++) {
            Rect b1 = bullets.get(j).getBounds();
            Rect e1 = enemies.get(i).getBounds();
            if (b1.intersect(e1)) {
                enemies.get(i).damageHP(5);
                bullets.remove(j);
                Log.d("TAG", "HERE: LOLTHEYTOUCHED");
            }
            if (h1.intersect(e1)){
                happy.damageHP(5);
            }
            if(enemies.get(i).getHP() <= 0){
                enemies.remove(i);
            }
            if(happy.getHP() <= 0){
                //end-screen                           !!!!!!!
            }
        }
    }
}
```

using this ArrayList:

```
        private ArrayList<Enemy> enemies = new ArrayList<Enemy>();
```

and adding to array like this:

```
   public void createEnemies() {
    Bitmap bmp = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
            R.drawable.female);
    if (enemyCounter < 24) {
        enemies.add(new Enemy(bmp, this, controls));
    }
    enemyCounter++;
}
```

I don't really understand what the problem is, I've been looking around for a while but can't really find anything that helps me. If you know or if you can link me someplace where they have a solution for a similar problem I'll be a very happy camper!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is the removal of elements from the `enemies` list. If the condition `enemies.get(i).getHP() <= 0` becomes true for an enemy object it may remove more than the intended object since your inner loop will continue to run.
The fix is to break out of the inner loop and start checking the next enemy object:

```
if(enemies.get(i).getHP() <= 0){
    enemies.remove(i);
    break;
}
```

Comment: This will fix the exception, however `remove` shifts all remaining enemies one index towards zero, so after you `break` out of the loop the next enemy will be skipped.

Comment: looks like this fixed it, simple and efficient. Thank you good sir!

Answer (score 3):

This happens when an "earlier" bullet has killed one or more of your enemies, and they are removed with `enemies.remove(i);` in such a way that now `i >= enemies.size()` (e.g. when it was the last enemy or enemies in the ArrayList). A "later" bullet will now be checked against an enemy index that no longer exists, and `enemies.get(i)` throws an `IndexOutOfBoundsException`.

It is generally a bad idea to thoughtlessly iterate over and remove from the same collection: you'll never know where your references end up (in this case `i` doesn't point anymore where you think it does). One way around this is to have a separate clean-up loop when you know your "dead" objects can no longer be referenced. To know which objects to clean-up, either:

- Use a property (`toBeDeleted`) for the objects that need to be removed, or
- Keep track of the set of indices that have been deprecated

So:

```
for (Enemy enemy : enemies) {

    // Check collisions with bullets.
    for (Bullet bullet : bullets) {
        if ( bullet.collides(enemy) ) {
            enemy.hit();
            bullet.setDelete(true);
        }
    }

    // Clean-up bullets.
    for (Iterator<Bullet> it = bullets.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
        if ( it.next().isDelete() )
             it.remove();

    // Enemy-Happy collision bonus optimization.
    if ( happy.collides(enemy) ){
        happy.hit();
    }

    // Flag dead enemies.
    if ( enemy.hp() <= 0 ) {
        enemy.setDelete(true);
    }
}

// Clean-up enemies.
for (Iterator<Enemy> it = enemies.iterator(); it.hasNext(); )
    if ( it.next().isDelete() )
        it.remove();
```

Comment: Another option is running through your collections backwards (`for (int i = enemies.size()-1; i >= 0; i--)`)...

Comment: Hi Eric, wouldn't this suffer from the "skip" after the remove? For example, if you are at index 0 and remove the enemy there, the iterator continues after collection is shifted.

Comment: (Assuming you're referring to the comment.) I have to add you still need to add @johlo's `break` to prevent the exception (which I think you already noticed). It won't result in a skip, because we are moving leftwards through the collection and only elements to the right will be shifted. So those elements will have the wrong `i`-value pointing at them, but we've already processed them earlier in this iteration and it is not a problem.

Comment: Hi Eric. Sorry, I meant your answer, since you are moving forward (left to right) in the collection. If we delete at index 0, then move to index 1, the item that was at 1 is now at 0 and has been skipped.

Comment: In the first nested loops I'm not deleting while iterating, just flagging objects for deletion. Later on I use `Iterator.remove()` in a loop, but it is safe to do so. See also: [Efficient equivalent for removing elements while iterating the Collection](http://stackoverflow.com/a/223929/1098673).